# Review Audit for a post that I already reviewed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, flags, review-audits

I got a [Review Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11292366) in the Late Answer queue for an answer that I already had [reviewed the day before](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11273619). Now because of this I couldn't flag the post as VLQ during the audit.

To pass the audit, I had to flag for another (but "wrong") reason.

While I don't see this as a critical problem, I'd suggest to exclude posts from audits that the same user already has handled before.

Comment: Wait till you get it a third time.

Comment: looks like a bug to me. you shouldnt be served audits of posts you reviewed before. thats dumb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there was a bug, we only excluded cross-queue post duplication between low quality, late answers and first post review queues, but not in-queue duplication.

A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (rev 2016.5.5.3544 on SO).