# Known Bad "Spam" audits using posts you already flagged as spam

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review-audits

(This came up as a follow up of a chat discussion today [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29740254#29740254))

It is currently possible to get served audits (known bad audits which have been selected because they were deleted by 6 spam flags) using a post that you yourself flagged as spam. This causes you to be unable to flag it (as you normally should to pass the audit) as spam (Because you have already done so, error message: "You have already raised this type of flag on this post"). You have to either write out a custom mod-flag to pass the audit or skip it.

This has happened to me (and others) multiple times. I guess the likelihood of this happening is vastly increased if you peruse chat rooms where the [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector) bot very often reports obvious spam that then gets group flagged and deleted.

I consider this a bug, and propose that you implement a way to not get served posts as audits that you yourself acted on previously.

Not only does this disturb the flow of your reviewing, it also makes no sense for the intended audit purpose (to test if you're paying attention)

Specific examples for SE employees to look at (by [ʞaʎess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4805174/kayess): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11878100) and [here](http://puu.sh/o5Cyl/0c46e2c1dc.png))

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285310/if-ive-already-voted-to-close-a-question-that-comes-up-in-the-triage-queue-i-c

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317101/review-audit-for-a-post-that-i-already-reviewed

Comment: On a positive note - at least you're not failing those audits - that'd be somewhat embarrassing :)

Comment: This is _far_ from the only problem with audits lately...

Comment: @AaronGillion Thats true, but its one that I think we can agree on is a bug and needs to be fixed.

Comment: I don't know if it would be easier to implement/use less resources but they could always suppress the error and then tell you the audit passed but you flag was not recorded as it was already flagged.

Comment: @NathanOliver the flag isn't recorded in any case

Comment: So `Skip` the audit. You don't get points for passing. Yeah, awkward interface - but the workaround seems both trivial and obvious. And it **does** test whether you're paying attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had indeed a bug here. We generate and cache a list of proper posts to be used as audits, but then a user could go and flag a post *after* it had been included in that cache. This should be fixed by now (build rev 2016.6.2.4585 on SO)